# Integrating simple Bluetooth functionality without microcontrollers

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, bluetooth

I have recently bought a Bluetooth HC-05 Module, and have followed many tutorials on integrating it with an Arduino, or a microcontroller. However I got interested in whether it is possible without one. And the task I need to achieve is pretty simple, just switching an LED on/off. The official bluetooth documentation is impossible to read, so I'm asking the question here, since I know many of you are experts in the subject.

Comment: No. Any attempt to build a Bluetooth adapter from discrete logic would result in the creation of a primitive microcontroller.

Comment: an Xbee does exactly this, with its awesome "direct IO" aka, DIO feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of all the interfacing that needs to be done. The module can't put a pin high when you send something to it, or low when you send something else. It's much more advanced, and involves communication standards that use timing. So if you would do this with 'simple components' (logic ports and the like) it would get extremely advanced, and you would simply have a little microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I would appreciate some directions on what would be the cheapest for future production HC-05 and Microcontroller type?

Comment: @user2332868 I honestly have no idea. You could ask this in [chat] probably, because unfortunately shopping questions are off topic on the main site.