# Can I connect a Bluetooth module without a microcontroller?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sensor, bluetooth

I am completely new to electrical engineering and was wondering whether or not I can connect a Bluetooth module to my phone without a microcontroller...

Is it possible to hook the module up to a power source and connect it directly to my phone without a microcontroller?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the Bluetooth module to do?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you have a Bluetooth module in mind? Some modules act as a peripheral, some are programmable.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - Essentially, I'm trying to make a thing which notifies the connected smart phone that the Bluetooth device (the Bluetooth module) has been disconnected. I'm trying to develop one of those wallet finder things. So, when the module gets disconnected due to the distance between it and the phone, I want the phone to get a notification...

Comment: @DanielGiesbrecht I was thinking about buying one of those BLE modules... something like this: [link](https://potentiallabs.com/cart/buy-nrf51822-ble-4-0-online-hyderabad-india?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8KS84cS71QIVxhiPCh3Reg5_EAQYBSABEgK8G_D_BwE)

Comment: Most Bluetooth modules that are more than just a USB dongle *are* microcontrollers with Bluetooth capability.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Oh, so would something like this: [link](https://potentiallabs.com/cart/buy-nrf51822-ble-4-0-online-hyderabad-india?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8KS84cS71QIVxhiPCh3Reg5_EAQYBSABEgK8G_D_BwE) do the job?

Comment: Yes nRF51822 can be used for this application. You can follow this video to see how to connect this to mobile phone. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmCmqN2i_Xo

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before: [Integrating simple Bluetooth functionality without microcontrollers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/133981/integrating-simple-bluetooth-functionality-without-microcontrollers)

There are some very small Bluetooth+micro controller solutions by ARM, and a few more can be found with a quick google search. Also you could see if WiFi is a good solution using the ESP8266 board, this has a small microcontroller included.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with some low cost bluetooth module with GPIOs. Basically the module itself is an MCU and can accept input outputs. The manufacturer also provides an interface software that let you customize these IO.

Example: Long press 1s to power on, press 1s when it's on to pair, etc.

So the answer to your question, yes.
As it's work related, won't mention any BT company names.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it depends. Long answer: most Bluetooth modules are connected to host (microcontroller, processor, etc.) over UART (Serial) connection. So they can't work without a microcontroller. Also, there are few microcontrollers with integrated Bluetooth and WiFi, such as ESP32, but they are just MCU and Bluetooth module in one IC.

Comment: Even some modules that traditionally talk over UART may have some sort of embedded MCU.